# Manipulate filesystem image files without loopback devices?

Tags: filesystems, mount, docker, loopback

I am trying to automate the creation of Raspberry Pi images under Docker virtual machine to run it in common `CI` systems like bitbucket-pipelines.

On physical system I am using "template" image, mount it't partitions to local directories, then populate it with script and unmount. To mount it I use script like following:

```
loopdevice=`losetup -f --show -P images/template.img`

echo $loopdevice > loopdevice

mkdir -p images/p1
mkdir -p images/p2
mkdir -p images/p3

mount ${loopdevice}p1 images/p1
mount ${loopdevice}p2 images/p2
mount ${loopdevice}p3 images/p3
```

(image contains 3 partitions, which are mounted to 3 directories).

Unfortunately, I can't use loopback devices inside Dcoker container if not priviledged and I can't make it priviledged inside Bitbucket pipelines. I see deadend here.

So, the question is: are there any Linux tools to manipulate filesystem image files without mounting them to loopback devices?

Comment: What filesystem type? Maybe you can mount it as [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) (e.g. `fuse2fs` for the ext family); although I'm not sure if you can easily specify an offset.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are tools to manipulate filesystems as you ask.  One such is the [mtools](https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/) package, which does FAT filesystems.  Another is [e2tools](https://e2tools.github.io), which does EXT2 and EXT3 filesystems.  Both of these are available in debian linux, and probably many others.
2. These tools will probably not deal with an image in a partition.  This should not be a problem.  Simply split your template into separate files for the partition table and partition contents (probably ahead of time), add your files into the filesystem images, and then `cat` the pieces together in the right order to produce the final disk image.

Answer (score 0):

I use and recommend [`guestfish`](https://libguestfs.org/guestfish.1.html), which is a part of [libguestfs, library for accessing and modifying VM disk images](https://libguestfs.org/).

I've found OpenStack's documentation includes a useful description of tools that do not require privileges: [Modify images — Virtual Machine Image Guide documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/modify-images.html)

Note that if you are making many disjoint changes you may benefit from running a `guestfish` daemon process and using its remote control mode - this saves on the (not insignificant) start-up time.

See [Remote control `guestfish` over a socket](https://libguestfs.org/guestfish.1.html#remote-control-guestfish-over-a-socket) of the `guestfish` manual.